# How to enable the title bar for all windows on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

A colleague of mine has the OS X title bar on all of his different displays and he is not sure how he it was enabled. I would love to have a different title bar per display/monitor.

Any ideas on how I can enable the title bar for multiple monitors?

In case its not called a title bar, this is what I am referring to:

[image: Title Bar]

Comment: It's called the menu bar. Title bars are what you find at the top of a window, and it's called that because it (usually) contains the window's title (as well as the close, minimize, and maximize buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of OS X 10.9 Mavericks. It's one of the enhancements to fullscreen introduced in 10.9. That is most likely what your friend is running. If you want it, Mavericks is a free upgrade from 10.8 Mountain Lion (which is what I assume you're running based on the tag) and I believe the sysreqs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot upgrade to Mavericks, here's a soft from [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/dual-monitors-and-os-x-lion-get-menubar-and-app-switcher-on-both-displays): [SecondBar](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33264/secondbar)